# throws ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined, has deprecated this is happening in my chat socket application

Tags: angular, sockets

this is my Service file code where i am getting error

```
 public sendMessage(msg: SocketMessage) {
this.socket.emit('check-message', msg);
```

}

```
checkNewMessages(): Observable<SocketMessage> {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      if (environment.production)
        this.socket.on('check-message', (message) => {
          observer.next(message);
        });

    })
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [throws ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272138/throws-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-emit-of-undefined)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your socket property is not defined. How do you declare it?

Maybe you have to declare in your service constructor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: how to set socker.io to local environment ??